# Rotate image arrow to particular location

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I rotate an image to particular location. The app gets user location and it should show destination direction, something like compass but only it does not show north it shows fixed location(lat,long). Here is the code I tried but it does not run, and i cant figure why. Long console only dipslays this:

> ```
> Latitude: 45.812682 Longitude: 15.989521
> Distance: 950.569458
> ```

This log is a part of above code(viewdidload)

```
    #define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
    double degrees = 0;
         - (void)viewDidLoad {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                // Check for GPS errors
                CLLocationManager *locationManager;

                // Get user location
                locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
                locationManager.delegate = self;
                locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
                [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
                [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
        }
                #define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
                #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
                -(void) calculateUserAngle:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)current {
                    double x = 0, y = 0 , deg = 0,delLon = 0;


                    float finish_latitude = 45.81;
                    float finish_longitude = 15.90;

                    float fixLon = finish_longitude;
                    float fixLat = finish_latitude;


                    delLon = fixLon - current.longitude;
                    y = sin(delLon) * cos(fixLat);
                    x = cos(current.latitude) * sin(fixLat) - sin(current.latitude) * cos(fixLat) * cos(delLon);
                    deg = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(y, x));

                    if(deg<0){
                        deg = -deg;
                    } else {
                        deg = 360 - deg;
                    }
                    degrees = deg; 
NSLog(@"degrees: %f",degrees);

                }

                -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D here = newLocation.coordinate;
                    [self calculateUserAngle:here];
                }

                - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
                {
                    direction.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((degrees-newHeading.trueHeading) * M_PI / 180);
 NSLog(@"Rotation: %f",(degrees-newHeading.trueHeading) * M_PI / 180);
                }
```

Comment: Where is your "degrees" declaration?

Comment: sorry forgot to type it